# My scene looks like it's a hobby model

Tags: photorealism

I don't know why my scene looks like a hobby model. (like one of those things people paint and glue) Picture below. Is there any way I can improve this and make it look more realistic? I want it to look like a photo taken from a plane. I think mainly it's the runway and planes that need some TLC. Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: I think the best way to improve it is to add small details, like image textures. You could also try sculpting or texture painting. I think you should edit your question a bit because it is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Patisawesome200 what do you mean by opinion based?

Comment: Opinion-based means that the answer to the question can vary from person to person based on things like what mood they are in, and does not have a concrete answer. For example, an opinion based question is "Does this look good", and a non-opinion-based question is "How do I get rid of this problem".

Comment: @Patisawesome200 is this better?

Comment: Yes. You could also improve the question by adding specific places to help on, such as the runway for the airplanes or the hull of the ship.

Comment: @Patisawesome200 better yet?

Comment: Yes. That's good.

Comment: @Patisawesome200 what do you mean by small details from image textures? And how would I sculpt/texture paint it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108618/discussion-between-patisawesome200-and-liaiwen).

Comment: Did you properly set your light up? When handling huge object, the environment light will become very critical part since that's how we can notice the thing is huge. And you might want to use a focal length at maybe 12mm or 14mm since we don't take picture on moon with Hubble space telescope to see a vessel in this kind of angle

Comment: @HikariTW Ok ill try that